# How to hide 'Home' button from appearing on supages - twenty eleven theme

Tags: navigation, theme-twenty-eleven

How could I make it so the '*Home*' button / text link doesn't appear in the top menu as the user navigates to a subpage??

*(So the menu stays the same accross)*

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52494/how-did-you-incorporate-woocommerce-in-your-own-wordpress-theme/59115#59115

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58417/using-disqus-how-to-stop-storing-comments-in-wp-database#autocomment76404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use a custom menu, which lets me take move any menu item around that I want.  Twenty Eleven does support a custom menu in the primary navigation area, so perhaps that would be your quickest solution.

Comment: Cam77 please accept this answer. Your 33% acceptance rate reflects on you badly.