# Using Disqus, how to stop storing comments in wp database?

Tags: comments, database, disqus

I'm using disqus comments system, but it keeps storing the comments in the wordpress database as well. Is there way to disable option to store comments in wordpress database because I don't see any use of it.

Answer (score 2):

The disqus plugin synchronizes your WordPress comments with the disqus system -- that's it's main purpose (own your own comments, etc). You can get around this by ditching the built in WordPress commenting system altogether, modifying your theme templates (probably just comments.php) to use the stand-alone disqus javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var disqus_shortname = ''; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
        var disqus_identifier = '<?php the_guid() ?>'; // globally unique identifier. *should* never change.
        var disqus_url = '<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>'; //link-back to this page
        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function () {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script');
            dsq.type = 'text/javascript';
            dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me a little what this actually does?

Comment: This code is straight from Disqus' standalone javascript code. Basically you're setting up some javascript variables unique to your site that identify the site and the current thing being commented on. Then Disqus' embed.js is created asynchronously and uses those variables to display the proper comment form.

Answer (score 2):

Did you already try disabling the sync from Disqus to WordPress?

[image]
(This is under *plugin settings* in the Disqus Dashboard view.)

FYI: The use of storing comments is to protect yourself against data loss if Disqus goes under, or if you want to migrate to a new plugin in the future.

Of course, you can manually sync with a setting as well, so barring an apocalyptic failure/shutdown of Disqus you're probably fine not storing the comments in your database.